# Android: Display/update clock in textview

Tags: android, timer, clock

I want to display and update a clock in my app. The time to be displayed is taken via a webservice.

Now how do I update the textview each second/minute? And also how do I keep the time synchronized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your time is already taken from a webservice, you should keep taking it at a fixed rate (like every second, minute, etc.) using a `Timer` with a `Service` or an `AsyncTask` implementation.

You can update your `TextView`'s content by

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).setText(formattedTime);
```

Where

- `R.id.myTextView` refers to the id of
  your `TextView` defined in your
  layout xml, and
- `formattedTime` is the time that
  you've got from the web service, and
  formatted it to be readable.

Comment: I know, but updating ever second/minute is very resource consuming

Answer (score 0):

You could have a thread running and have it sleep the required number of minutes/seconds (after being converted from ms). And then update this text through the thread via a handler that updates it for you. However; one thing you can potentially use is the system clock to do this for you (If they are the same).